# reformat characters in json data

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, reddit

I am retrieving data from reddit json. and some data is like that:

```
The actual resolution of this image is 3067x2276, not 4381x3251. See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn/wiki/index#wiki_resolution.3F_what_is_that_and_how_can_i_find_it.3F) page for information on how to find out what the resolution of an image is.
```

i want to insert the data into `<p></p>` on my page but the link is as it is above (not clickable).

Notice when i try to post it on stackoverflow, it very nicely reformats into a clickable link. How do i do that?

**reformatted by stackoverflow:**

The actual resolution of this image is 3067x2276, not 4381x3251. See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn/wiki/index#wiki_resolution.3F_what_is_that_and_how_can_i_find_it.3F) page for information on how to find out what the resolution of an image is.

How do i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like I cheated, but inspecting the OP in my browser, I get...

```
<p>The actual resolution of this image is 3067x2276, not 4381x3251. See <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn/wiki/index#wiki_resolution.3F_what_is_that_and_how_can_i_find_it.3F" rel="nofollow noreferrer">this</a> page for information on how to find out what the resolution of an image is.</p>
```

In other words, if you find `[words](URL)`, replace it with:

```
<a href="URL">words</a>
```

This little regex tries to capture the contents of [] followed by ().  Checking for http may be insufficient depending on the sort of links you expect...

```
let regex = /\[(.*?)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/g;
let matches = regex.exec(line);
// matches ought to contains words and a potential url
if (matches.length > 2 && matches[2].startsWith("http://")) {
    // matches[2] is probably a url, so...
    let replace = `<a href="${matches[2]}">${matches[1]}</a>`
    // ...
}
```

Comment: so i look for "](" and take the words before and the url after? is there a straightforward function to achieving that?

Comment: The square braces are simple enough.  Followed by parens is simple enough.  Detecting a url can be tough if, for example, you can find any scheme.  A simple heuristic would be to look for http colon slash slash anything, and call that a url

Comment: @KwokWenJian, I took a shot at it.  Untested.

Comment: may i ask, if there are two or more of such links to match, how do i deal with it?

Comment: would you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644762/regex-if-else-statement-failing

Answer (score 1):

Start with Regular Expressions, basically wildcards on steroids.
`/\[.*\]\(.*\)/`, While looking weird, will find `[*](*)` where `*` can be any length string. All this can do is find the first index of this appearing. I tried looking but i'm not the best with JS.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp