# regex if else statement failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex

here's a function that checks if there's a link in text (if so, replaces it with a clickable one)

example:

The actual resolution of this image is 3067x2276, not 4381x3251. See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn/wiki/index#wiki_resolution.3F_what_is_that_and_how_can_i_find_it.3F) page for information on how to find out what the resolution of an image is.

```
function getTopComment(permalink) {
  var fullLink = "https://www.reddit.com" + permalink + ".json?sort=top";
  $.getJSON(fullLink, function foo(result) {
    var rawComment = result[1].data.children[0].data.body;
    var regExp = /\[(.*?)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/g;
    var matches = regExp.exec(rawComment);
    if (matches.length > 2) {
      var replace = `<a href="${matches[2]}">${matches[1]}</a>`;
      var cleanComment = rawComment.replace(matches[0], replace);
      $("#text").append('<p>' + cleanComment + '</p>');
    } else {
      $("#text").append('<p>hello</p>');
    }
  });
}
```

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="art" class="img column1">
    </div>
    <div id="text" class="comment column2">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I tried running it on chrome's javascript console, replacing `$("#text").append`... with `console.log("hello")`, and it works. Why does it not work on jsfiddle?

Comment: Because you need to load the jquery ajax library for it to work in js-fiddle maybe?

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: @admcfajn i chose jquery3.3.1 on jsfiddle. do i need ajax?

Comment: @TylerRoper done! sorry

Comment: @KwokWenJian I'm not 100% sure if the library will include ajax by default (probably does) or if reddit will allow ajax requests from jsfiddle (very possible it won't), I'd try to output something directly within the response (no regex, no if) to see if the response is even returning.

Comment: OP saying that `console.log("hello")` *works* in place of the `$("#text").append()` rules out jQuery or AJAX being the issue. If either of those were responsible, the code would fail at `$.getJSON` and never make it to the `console.log()`.

Comment: i have resorted to try, catch. and it works, although i think it is not the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

use try and catch instead

```
function getTopComment(permalink) {
    var fullLink = "https://www.reddit.com" + permalink + ".json?sort=top";
  $.getJSON(fullLink, function foo(result) {
    var rawComment = result[1].data.children[0].data.body;
    try {
        var regExp = /\[(.*?)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/g;
        var matches = regExp.exec(rawComment);
      var replace = `<a href="${matches[2]}">${matches[1]}</a>`;
      var cleanComment = rawComment.replace(matches[0], replace);
      $("#text").append('<p>' + cleanComment + '</p>');
    } catch(err) {
      $("#text").append('<p>' + rawComment + '</p>');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I was just looking at the code, including the handling of reg ex result.  Try/catch is helping  because the non matching regex will generate null.  This try/catch is fine, or you could also guard the replace logic with `if (matches && matches.length > 2) { // replace logic here }`

Answer (score 0):

`exec` returns `null` if regex not matched result. Just check it at first.

```
...
if (matches && matches.length > 2) {
...
```